# calculate overlap in timestamp in R

Tags: r, timestamp, overlap

I want to calculate the overlap between two timestaps ranges with "overlap" function. And save if there is overlap, and the interval of the overlap in a data table.

I've tried to work with the function to understand how it works, trying this code.

```
> a = c(as.Date("2012-01-03 18:00:00"), as.Date("2012-02-03 18:00:00"))
> b = c(as.Date("2012-02-01 19:00:00"), as.Date("2012-03-03 18:00:00"))
> Overlap(a,b)
[1] 2
```

The problem is that only takes into account days and no the time. I would like to use the time as well.

Comment: What package is this function in?

Comment: DescTools, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DescTools/versions/0.99.19/topics/%25overlaps%25

Answer (score 0):

We may apply `as.POSIXct` when time is to be considered, rather than `as.Date`.

```
a <- as.POSIXct(c("2012-01-03 18:00:00", "2012-02-03 18:00:00"))
b <- as.POSIXct(c("2012-02-01 19:00:00", "2012-03-03 18:00:00"))
```

When converting `as.POSIXct` into `numeric` we get seconds; proof:

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(a), origin="1970-01-01")  # origin is mostly "1970-01-01"
# [1] "2012-01-03 18:00:00 CET" "2012-02-03 18:00:00 CET"
```

In this way we could calculate the `intersect` of `a` and `b`, take the `range`, and convert it back `as.POSIXct` to get the overlap.

```
as.POSIXct(range(intersect(as.numeric(a)[1]:as.numeric(a)[2], 
                           as.numeric(b)[1]:as.numeric(b)[2])), origin="1970-01-01")
# [1] "2012-02-01 19:00:00 CET" "2012-02-03 18:00:00 CET"
```

This also should work with your `Overlap()` function (not tested).